# Scala pattern matching guard breaks pattern matching exhaustiveness?

Tags: scala

Why does guarding a case when pattern matching break pattern matching exhaustiveness in Scala?

```
chris@chris-870Z5E-880Z5E-680Z5E:~/dev/bitcoins-core$ sbt console
[info] Loading project definition from /home/chris/dev/bitcoins-core/project
[info] Set current project to bitcoin-s-core (in build file:/home/chris/dev/bitcoins-core/)
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_101).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> sealed trait A 
defined trait A

scala> case class B() extends A 
defined class B

scala> case class C() extends A 
defined class C

scala> val b : A = B() 
b: A = B()

scala> b match { case b : B => () }
<console>:15: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: C()
       b match { case b : B => () }
       ^

scala> b match { case b : B if b.isInstanceOf[B] => ()  }

scala>
```

Note on the last line there is no exhaustiveness warning, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is an [open issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5365).

[A comment by Adriaan Moors](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5365?focusedCommentId=72366&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-72366):

> I understand it's disappointing, and it's not very intuitive why we bail out when there are guards, but our key design goal is not to have spurious warnings, as that would undermine their utility while annoying a lot of users.

Comment: But the more recent result is the PR by Zaugg, which includes speculations about what is possible. A complete answer to "why is it like this?" would include those partial results. What should we expect of a guard condition in these cases? Because intuitively, it seems like some cases are obviously provable.

Comment: I just answered what little I know - feel free to write more :)

Comment: I know what you mean!

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is unable to give warning in the second case where `isInstanceOf` is used, may be because it thinks user knows the type information of the variable `b`.

**Scenario 1**

```
scala> b match { case b : B if b.isInstanceOf[B] => ()  }

scala> def f(b: A) = b match { case b : B if b.isInstanceOf[B] => ()  }
f: (b: A)Unit

scala> f(C())
scala.MatchError: C() (of class C)
  at .f(<console>:14)
  ... 33 elided
```

**Scenario 2**

```
scala> val b: A = C()
b: C = C()

scala> b match { case b : B if b.isInstanceOf[B] => ()  }
scala.MatchError: C() (of class C)
  ... 33 elided
```

Comment: There is no point of pattern matching in `scenario 2` since the type of `b` is already known.

Comment: It still doesn't answer the original question

Comment: @ChrisStewart  why are you using `isInstanceOf` when pattern matching internally does the same thing for you.

Comment: Just as an example, something simple to put in the guard.